# php PDO lock tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In this script I have:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=name; charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
$db -> exec('LOCK TABLES `table1`, `table2` WRITE');
// Do some stuff here
$db -> exec('UNLOCK TABLES');
```

The problem is that the tables don't seem to be locked. Multiple instances of the script are executed at the same time. The

```
// Do something here
```

code still fails to do stuff atomically as would be expected with the LOCK TABLES statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Also I have noticed that although I don't explicitly lock other tables that I use (for example `table3`) I can still read/write to them. That should not be possible according to the mySQL manual.

**EDIT:**

The `// Do some stuff here` code instantiates a few classes that do the DB work but which share the same `$db` PDO connection.

This should not be the cause of the problem as I understand it, exactly because they share the same connection. The lock tables statement should be 'inherited' by them.

Comment: How do you know the script is executing multiple times at the same time?

Comment: Well for starters it was designed to be executed multiple times at the same time.
After that I can see that the data in the DB is wrong :)
That wouldn't be the case if there weren't multiple instances of the script executing and if LOCK TABLES worked :)

Comment: Does your user have the privileges to lock tables?

Comment: Yep, checked that also!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a little off. Add `WRITE` after each table name:

```
$db -> exec('LOCK TABLES `table1` WRITE, `table2` WRITE');
```